# How to highlight the similarity of the value between rows and columns?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to highlight the similarity between two rows and the similarity between two columns. With mouse over of a rows (columns) should visualise the similarities of the rows (columns) to all other rows (columns). For example if i go to an row. it should show the similarity of the value in the other rows and column. Only the value between the rows and columns should to be shown. The other should be faded out. Ive tried it but its not working.

```
  svg.selectAll() 
      .data(mapData.data, function(d) {return d.group +':'+ d.variable;})
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.variable) })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.group) })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
        .style("fill", function(d) { return colour(d.value)})
      .on("mouseenter", () => tooltip.style("visibility", "visible"))
      .on("mousemove", (e, d) => {
        tooltip.html("The exact value is: " + d.value);
        tooltip
        .style("top", `${e.layerY + 24}px`)
        .style("left", `${e.layerX + 24}px`)
        .each(function(d){
            if(variable.indexOf(d) != -1)
            d3.select(this).attr("class", "tr");})
      })
      .on("mouseleave", () => tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden"))  
      console.log(mapData)
```

```
<style>
  body {
    margin: 50px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  .tr:hover{
  background-color: #ffa;
  }
</style>

  <p>First Tutorial</p>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
  <div id="container"> </id>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, when an item is hovered, the other items should be highlighted differently. Those with more close value should be more bright and those with more distant value should be pale. Am I right?

Comment: yes. Example: The first column is selected, then the similarities to all other columns are to be hovered. The same applies to rows.
You try to think about what it means that 2 columns/rows are "similar", how this similarity is calculated and then how this similarity is represented in my visualisation.

Comment: So similar value is a value whose delta from the current is less than 3. Right?

Comment: Yes. Thats what i want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use this simple routine:

```js
const highlightSimilar = value => {
  const isSimilar = v => Math.abs(v - value) < 3;
    svg.selectAll('rect').each(function(d) {
    const opacity = !value || isSimilar(d.value) ? 1 : 0;
    d3.select(this).style('opacity', opacity);
  })
}
```

It should be called on `mouseenter` (with value) and `mouseleave` (with `null`):

```js
svg.selectAll("rect")     
  .on("mouseenter", function(e, d){
    highlightSimilar(d.value);
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function(e, d){
    highlightSimilar(null);
  })
```

See it working in the fiddle:

```js
    var data = [
      [2.56, 8.52, 4.92, 2.58, 8.44, 2.29],
      [7.94, 8.42, 7.71, 7.0, 8.13, 5.63],
      [1.38, 3.29, 2.38, 2.85, 1.38, 1.77],
      [1.31, 2.48, 1.04, 1.21, 1.83, 1.48],
      [1.58, 8.19, 4.75, 3.38, 4.83, 1.46],
      [4.48, 4.08, 4.13, 1.73, 1.37, 2.58],
      [2.56, 8.52, 4.92, 2.58, 8.44, 2.29]
   ];

    var rowLabels = [
      "rowOne",
      "rowTwo",
      "rowThree",
      "rowFour",
      "rowFive",
      "rowSix",
      "rowSeven",
    ];
    var columnLabels = [
      "columnOne",
      "columnTwo",
      "columnThree",
      "columnFour",
      "columnFive",
      "columnSix",
    ];
    
    const myData = data.reduce((res, item, index) => {
      const group = rowLabels[index];
      item.forEach((value, colIndex) => {
        res.min = Math.min(value, res.min);
        res.max = Math.max(value, res.max);
        res.data.push({group, variable: columnLabels[colIndex], value});
      });
      return res;
    }, {data: [], min: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, max: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY});
    
    console.log(myData);
        
    
    var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 100},
  width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#container")
.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
  .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


// Build X scales and axis:
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([ 0, width ])
  .domain(rowLabels) // myGroups
  .padding(0.01);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

// Build X scales and axis:
var y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([ height, 0 ])
  .domain(columnLabels) // myVars
  .padding(0.01);
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// Build color scale
var myColor = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range(["#0000ff", "#00ff00"])
  .domain([myData.min,myData.max])

  svg.selectAll()
      .data(myData.data, function(d) {return d.group+':'+d.variable;})
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.group) })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.variable) })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
      .style("fill", function(d) { return myColor(d.value)} )
      
      
 var tooltip = d3.select("#container")
      .append("div")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("visibility", "hidden")
      .style("background", "#ffffff")
      
const highlightSimilar = value => {
  const isSimilar = v => Math.abs(v - value) < 3;
    svg.selectAll('rect').each(function(d) {
    const opacity = !value || isSimilar(d.value) ? 1 : 0;
    d3.select(this)
        .style('opacity', opacity);
  })
}

svg.selectAll("rect")     
      .on("mouseenter", function(e, d){
        tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
        highlightSimilar(d.value);
      })
      .on("mousemove", function(e, d){
        tooltip.html("The exact value is: " + d.value);
        tooltip
        .style("top", `${e.layerY + 24}px`)
        .style("left", `${e.layerX + 24}px`);
      })
      .on("mouseleave", function(e, d){
        tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
        highlightSimilar(null);
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
<div id="container"/>
```

Comment: Glad to help :)